# Cannot find Cocoa Pod I made? `pod search ...` yields no results

Tags: ios, command-line, dependencies, cocoapods

I've made my first cocoa pod here: https:// github.com/vivekseth/VSSPritz/ (Its an open source implementation of Spritz (I borrowed heavily from a project called OSSpritz))

I followed the instructions in http:// guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create and can see my pod at http:// cocoadocs.org/docsets/VSSpritz/0.1.3/index.html .

I can even install my pod, by adding `pod "VSSpritz"` to my Podfile.

But, `pod search` does not find it.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have looked at the documentation.

http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_search

Using `pod search --full VSSPritz` did the trick.